# final non-null field becomes null

Tags: java, jls

How is this even possible?

```
public class WritableByteChannelEndpoint extends Endpoint<ByteBuffer> {

    private final WritableByteChannel channel;

    public WritableByteChannelEndpoint(WritableByteChannel channel, Observable<ByteBuffer> observable) {
        super(observable);
        this.channel = Objects.requireNonNull(channel);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onNext(ByteBuffer input) {
        assert channel != null;
        // ...
    }

}
```

I get an assertion error in that line. For some reason, that I can not understand, `channel` is null.

This occurs every once in a while, when I am executing unit tests with JUnit.

Is it *theoretically* possible, that the whole `WritableByteChannelEndpoint` instance is already garbage-collected and `channel` is set to null, but some other object still has a (weak?) reference to it?

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a race condition? Does the superclass constructor leak the instance at all?

Comment: yes, the super constructor passes itself to some async running task.

Comment: ok, got it. That async task is calling `onNext` before the child constructor even finished. If you like, you can write this as an answer, I'd accept.

Comment: Answer written. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before suspecting weird GC behavior through weak references, consider a more likely race condition: Your constructor calls the superclass constructor before setting `this.channel`. The superclass constructor can hence leak the `WritableByteChannelEndpoint` correspnding to `this` that is being constructed, leading to `onNext` being called before the subclass constructor has had a chance to set the value of `channel`. Your final field doesn't *become* null, since it doesn't have a chance to be non-null in time (intermittently).